# Compat-wirless build on Yocto kernel

Tags: android, yocto

Hi I am trying to build compat-wireless component for Qualcom's APQ8064 on Yocto kernel.

When I build compat-wireless package provided by Qualcom as part of code-aroura android am able to see cfg80211.ko and ath6kl_sdio.ko ath6kl_usb.ko components are generated successfully.

But when I build compat-wireless package with Yocto kernel (ver 3.1.0) as standalone am seeing only wlan.o (i.e ath6kl_usb.ko) being generated. (I dont see cfg80211.ko and ath6kl_sdio.ko)

Enabling the CFG flags for ath6kl_sdio.ko support ends up with lot of compilation/dependency issues. 
Has anyone faced the similar issue? Please provide suggestions. Also I am not able to understand, how android build resolves these dependencies and builds successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using bitbake with the -c menuconfig linux-yocto arguments. Then find you driver type 'h' for help and you should see the dependencies tree.